# How do I get the "Your Guesses" section to reset after either a win or until the number of guesses is greater than 9?

Tags: javascript, random

```js
var computerChoices = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

var wins = 0;
var losses = 0; 
var GuessesLeft = 9;

document.onkeyup = function () {

  var computerGuess = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];  
  var userGuess = event.key; 
  var yourGuess = userGuess;
  
  if (userGuess = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)]) {
    
    if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
      wins++;
    }
    else if (GuessesLeft == 0) {
      losses++;
      GuessesLeft = 9;
    }
    else if (yourGuess.length < 0) {
    }
    else {
      GuessesLeft--;
    }
  var score =
  "<p>" + "Wins: " + wins + "</p>" +
  "<p>" + "Losses: " + losses + "</p>" +
  "<p>" + "Guesses Left: " + GuessesLeft + "</p>";
  document.querySelector("#game").innerHTML = score;
  var yourGuess = " " + yourGuess;
  document.querySelector("#Guesses").innerHTML += yourGuess;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>The Psychic Game</h1>
 <p>Guess what letter the computer is thinking of! You have 9 chances.  </p>
 <div id="game">
 </div>  
 <p id="Guesses">Your Guesses:</p>
</body>
```

[image]

I need the "your guesses" section to reset once `guesses left` is `0` or `wins` goes up by one.

Do I need to have a function for this? I have tried a lot of things, and I do not know that much about functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your current setup, a function would be a great first step towards solving your issue. Functions allow you to define multi-step behavior as a single action for use in multiple places.

Let's take a look at your requirement: I need the "your guesses" section to reset once "guesses left" is 0 or "wins" goes up by one. We have our behavior: reset the "your guesses section" as well as two conditions: (1) guesses left is 0 or (2) "wins" goes up by one.

With a function we can encapsulate that behavior as so:

```
var resetGuesses = function () {
  GuessesLeft = 9; // reset our model
  document.querySelector("#Guesses").innerHTML = ''; // reset our view
}
```

Your two conditions are already set up with your if/else logic, allowing you to drop this behavior into their appropriate situations like so:

```
if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
  wins++;
  resetGuesses();
}
else if (GuessesLeft == 0) {
  losses++;
  resetGuesses();
}
```

[See this solution in action on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lav4f95u/9/)

Comment: That has really helped me understand what functions do! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use selector to select the "your guesses" section and edit the innerHTML

[Check Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_innerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<h1>The Psychic Game</h1>
<p>Guess what letter the computer is thinking of! You have 9 chances. </p>
<div id="game">

</div>
<p id="Guesses">Your Guesses:</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var computerChoices = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

    var wins = 0;
    var losses = 0;
    var GuessesLeft = 9;

    document.onkeyup = function () {

        var computerGuess = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
        var userGuess = event.key;
        var yourGuess = userGuess;

        if (userGuess = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)]) {

            if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
                wins++;
            }
            else if (GuessesLeft == 0) {
                losses++;
                GuessesLeft = 9;
            }
            else if (yourGuess.length < 0) {
            }
            else {
                GuessesLeft--;
            }
            var score =
                "<p>" + "Wins: " + wins + "</p>" +
                "<p>" + "Losses: " + losses + "</p>" +
                "<p>" + "Guesses Left: " + GuessesLeft + "</p>";
            document.querySelector("#game").innerHTML = score;
            var yourGuess = " " + yourGuess;
            if (GuessesLeft == 9) {
                document.querySelector("#Guesses").innerHTML = "Your Guesses:";
            } else {
                document.querySelector("#Guesses").innerHTML += yourGuess;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```